# How to create this custom ANN using tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to create this custom ANN using tensorflow. Here is image of the toy network and code.

[image]

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

in = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4], , dtype="float32")
y_true = np.array([10, 11], , dtype="float32")


# w is vector of weights
# y_pred = np.array([in[0]*w[0]+in[1]*w[0]], [in[2]*w[1]+in[3]*w[1]] )
# y_pred1 = 1 / (1 + tf.math.exp(-y_pred)) # sigmoid activation function

def loss_fun(y_true, y_pred1):
    loss1 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(y_pred1 - y_true, 2))   

# model.compile(loss=loss_fun,  optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The output of this network goes to another ANN to the right and I know that stuff, but don't know how can I create the connections, update the `w`, `y_pred`, and compile the model. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ought to work

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def y_pred(x, w):
    return [x[0]*w[0]+x[1]*w[0], x[2]*w[1]+x[3]*w[1]]

def loss_fun(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(y_pred - y_true, 2))
        
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype="float32")
y_true = np.array([10, 11], dtype="float32")
w = tf.Variable(initial_value=np.random.normal(size=(2)), name='weights', dtype=tf.float32)
xt = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
yt = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_true)
sgd_opt = tf.optimizers.SGD()
training_steps = 100
display_steps = 10
for step in range(training_steps):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(w)
        yp = y_pred(xt, w)
        loss = loss_fun(yt, yp)
    dl_dw = tape.gradient(loss, w)
    sgd_opt.apply_gradients(zip([dl_dw], [w]))
    if step % display_steps == 0:
        print(loss, w)
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to write a separate activation function or I can use built-in functions?

Comment: @ewr3243 You can use built-in activations, just change y_pred function (or run "yp" through the activation). You would probably want to change your loss to be cross-entropy as well, and also the y_true would look different. You need to be a little careful with GradientTape if you start changing stuff because it needs everything to be tensors (not e.g. np.ndarrays).